# How to get O365 mailbox with Powershell on a local Exchange?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I will try to explain you with my poor English vocabulary, my problem :

I have a PW script to do to activate mailbox archive. When I connect to my local exchange web interface, I see mailboxes with type mailbox attribute is "Office 365". When I try to activate archive on O365, it told me "Your mailbox is synchronized with a local exchange, u have to activate archive on the local exchange ". As I said previously, I see these mailboxes with web interface but when I want to "Get-mailbox" in local one, the result only show me mailboxes with mailbox type "User".

Do you know how I can see my O365 mailboxes with PowerShell on my local exchange?

PS: I already tried to connect to my O365 with ExchangeOnlineManagement and put the "get-mailbox" result in a variable. Then I close my ExchangeOnlineConnection and I did something like this :

```
$test | enable-Mailbox -Archive
```

But the answer is always the same : "John DOE doesn't have a mailbox on the local Exchange"

Thanks for advance for your help.

NEW INFO : Someone told me to use "Get-RemoteMailbox" and "Enable-RemoteMailbox". I try this tomorrow and I update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Exchange Management Shell, and then run the following cmdlet:
Enable-RemoteMailbox  -Archive

Wait for two cycles of directory synchronization to run (about six hours). Or force directory synchronization. For more info about how to do this, see [Synchronize your directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity).